# Typescript type always undefined when using requirejs

Tags: typescript, requirejs, undefined

I'm trying to work out how to use requirejs with typescript. I'm struggling to get the most simple example to work! I have the following...

**Person.ts**

```
export class Person {
    name: string;

    constructor() {
        this.name = 'simon';
    }
}
```

and **default.html**...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="require.js" data-main="Person"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['Person'], function () {
        var simon = new Person();
        alert(simon.name);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

All files including require.js are in the same folder.

The line in default.html...
`var simon = new Person();`

always results in Person being undefined!

Comment: TypeScript just emits JavaScript files (which I hope you're doing?). RequireJS doesn't care where the JS file came from so that aspect isn't really relevant.

Comment: yes my ts files are transpiled into js fies. Ive given the full story as thr issue could be with the import of the Person.ts

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an argument in your `require` callback function

```
require(['Person'], function (Person) {
    var simon = new Person();
    alert(simon.name);
});
```

`Person` won't be available globally unless you attach it to the `window` object, that is why you always get `undefined`.

Hope it helps